# Endless animation function that receives a parameter on 'hover' event

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, jquery-animate

The idea is to execute an animation while the cursor is over a div. I've done this other times but now the function with the animation receives a parameter and if I add the parameter the page blows up. Without that last call to the function the code doesn't crash the page.
Please check my code:

```
function OnHover() {
    function Animation(obj) {
        obj.stop().animate({ top: '20px' }, 600).animate({ top: '0px' }, 600, Animation(obj));
}

    $('#infobox').hover(
        function(event) {
            $circle = $(event.target).children().first();
            Animation($circle);
        }, 
        function(event) {
            $circle = $(event.target).children();
            $circle.stop();
        }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used this workaround:

```
$target = undefined;
$("#wrapper .infobox").mouseenter(event, function animate() {
                if (typeof $target == 'undefined')
                    $target = $(event.target).children();

                $target.animate({ marginTop: "+=40px" }, 600);
                $target.animate({ marginTop: "-=40px" }, 600, animate);
            }
        );
        $("#wrapper .infobox").mouseleave(function() {
                $target.stop(true, false).animate({ marginTop: '20px'}, 300);
                $target = undefined;
            }
        );
```